# databound drop down list missing first record from database

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have several asp:dropdown lists that I am trying to populate from a database file. When I query the database file the First Record does not get added to the dropdown list. When I add an "ORDER BY" to my query to make the dropdown list sorted then the first record in the "ORDER BY" seems to get lost. Example: the first query seems to drop the first record in the file called: "Maintenance" In the second query with the ORDER BY the "Maintenance" record shows up but the record "Cost" seems to get dropped. Since "Cost" would be the first record within the dropdown list due to the alphabetical order by. Why does the first record within the data seem to get dropped for the dropdownlist? Has anyone ran into an issue similar? I have tried changing the CausesValidation, AppendDataBoundItems, etc without any luck. I also have "If Not Page.IsPostBack Then" in the Page_Load. Any ideas?
Thanks,
Erin

Comment: apparently the issue with this was the result of me adding the following line of code:Dim r As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While r.Read(). Evidently the Read() was the resaon the first record was not being displayed in the dropdown list. When I commented out the "While r.Read()" in my code then all of the values displayed in my dropdown list.

Comment: Erin I had the same exact issue today and your follow up post was invaluable to me.  I had this scenario going on: Dim reader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If (reader.HasRows) Then  
      While reader.Read()
 'fill ddl
End While.  After commenting out the While reader.Read(0 and End While - the first item in the list appeared again.  I often struggle with when to use .HasRows and While...I used both which must be wrong ?